# When NP complete becomes NP hard

Tags: np-complete, np, np-hard

Generally, assuming we have a NPC problem. Adding more constraint to it (making it more difficult), is it possible that problem become NPH? I know the difference between NPC and NPH but I don't know how to show that adding new constraints to existing NPC problem will make it NPH or still remains NPC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course can an additional constraint transform an NPC to an NPH problem. Further there could be no person on World able to proof that.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Do you know any document or papers to show it? I am just curious to see.

Comment: sorry, no paper. but an additional contraint can be seen as a new problem. A new problem can be harder or easier to solve.